# Google SSO - The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID

Tags: google-signin, google-sso

I'm trying to implement Sign In with Google for my Ruby / Rails app and I have followed the OAuth configuration setup as per [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid) from Google.

I've added the snippet and got the Sign In with Google button displaying fine. The sign in fields display correctly but once inputting valid credentials, nothing happens and I get the error:

'The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.'

For testing locally, the guide says for the Authorized Javascript Origins, you need to use both `http://localhost` and `http://localhost:3000`, which I have done. But I assume I'm getting this error because the page which has the snippet on it has a subdomain, and therefore the URL is `xxxx.localhost:3000`, rather than `localhost:3000` and they no longer match. Google's OAuth configuration doesn't seem to support subdomains either - does anyone know how I can get around this?

Code:

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="XXXXX"
     data-context="signin"
     data-ux_mode="popup"
     data-login_uri="http://localhost:3000"
     data-auto_prompt="false">
</div>

<div class="g_id_signin"
     data-type="standard"
     data-shape="rectangular"
     data-theme="outline"
     data-text="signin_with"
     data-size="large"
     data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>

<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

I should be getting a http request with some user information to an endpoint of mine upon successful authentication, but instead I'm getting a javascript error - 'The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.'

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I've added it in now 

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be programming related.   maybe try web apps Stack exchange.   If you need help with the  google analytics website